# cutting a square out of a mesh in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, mesh

In essence what I want to do is project a square onto an arbitrary mesh.
Basically the DecalGeometry that is already in three.js and not far from what is here https://threejs.org/examples/?q=decal#webgl_decals

The issue that I am having is that I want to make sure that if I where to flatten the square the dimensions would end up at exactly `a,b`.

This also means that I can't just set the projection plane to `a,b` as the mesh will warp. For instance if I project onto a cylinder and the size of the square is large enough it should wrap to the oposite side of the cylinder.

Are there any known algorithms for doing this?